# Is it possible keydown and keyup event will change the interval of the setInterval?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a simple snake game by javascript, I try to add a feature that when the user holds the shift key, the snake will speed up. But right now when I hold shift for a short time it works fine, but if I hold it for a long time the game will pause (snake stop moving). Here is my code, please help me fix it.

```js
var grid_size = 20;
var grid_num = 20;
var player_x = Math.floor(Math.random() * grid_num);
var player_y =Math.floor(Math.random() * grid_num);
var apple_x = Math.floor(Math.random() * grid_num);
var apple_y = Math.floor(Math.random() * grid_num);
var x_direction = 0;
var y_direction = 0;
var trail = [];
var tail = 5;
var normal_speed = 1000 / 10
var speed = 1000 / 10;
var game_status = 0;
var my_game;

// 1. Create the button
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "Do Something";

// 2. Append somewhere
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(button);

// 3. Add event handler
button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
  clearInterval(my_game);
  my_game = setInterval(game, speed);
});

window.onload = function() {
 canv = document.getElementById("gc");
 context = canv.getContext("2d");
 document.addEventListener("keydown", keyPush);
 document.addEventListener("keyup", keyRelease);
}

function game() {
 player_x += x_direction;
 player_y += y_direction;
 if (player_x < 0) {
  player_x = grid_num - 1;
 }
 if (player_x > grid_num - 1) {
  player_x = 0;
 }
 if (player_y < 0) {
  player_y = grid_num - 1;
 }
 if (player_y > grid_num - 1) {
  player_y = 0;
 }
 context.fillStyle = "black";
 context.fillRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
 context.fillStyle = "lime";
 for(var i = 0; i < trail.length; i++) {
  context.fillRect(trail[i].x * grid_size, trail[i].y * grid_size, grid_size - 2, grid_size - 2);
  if(trail[i].x == player_x && trail[i].y == player_y) {
   if (game_status == 0) {
    tail = 5;
   } else {
    endGame();
    return;
   }
  }
 }
 trail.push({x:player_x, y:player_y});
 while(trail.length > tail) {
  trail.shift();
 }
 if (apple_x == player_x && apple_y == player_y) {
  tail++;
  apple_x = Math.floor(Math.random() * grid_num);
  apple_y = Math.floor(Math.random() * grid_num);
 }
 context.fillStyle = "red";
 context.fillRect(apple_x * grid_size, apple_y * grid_size, grid_size - 2, grid_size - 2);
}

function keyPush(keyEvent) {
 switch(keyEvent.keyCode) {
  case 37:
   if (x_direction == 1) {
    break;
   }
      game_status++;
   x_direction = -1;
   y_direction = 0;
   break;
  case 38:
   if (y_direction == 1) {
    break;
   }
      game_status++;
   x_direction = 0;
   y_direction = -1;
   break;
  case 39:
   if (x_direction == -1) {
    break;
   }
      game_status++;
   x_direction = 1;
   y_direction = 0;
   break;
  case 40:
   if (y_direction == -1) {
    break;
   }
      game_status++;
   x_direction = 0;
   y_direction = 1;
   break;
  case 65:
   if (x_direction == 1) {
    break;
   }
      game_status++;
   x_direction = -1;
   y_direction = 0;
   break;
  case 87:
   if (y_direction == 1) {
    break;
   }
      game_status++;
   x_direction = 0;
   y_direction = -1;
   break;
  case 68:
   if (x_direction == -1) {
    break;
   }
      game_status++;
   x_direction = 1;
   y_direction = 0;
   break;
  case 83:
   if (y_direction == -1) {
    break;
   }
      game_status++;
   x_direction = 0;
   y_direction = 1;
   break;
  case 16:
   clearInterval(my_game);
   speed = normal_speed * 0.5;
   my_game = setInterval(game, speed);
   break;
 }
}

function keyRelease(keyEvent) {
 switch(keyEvent.keyCode) {
  case 16:
   clearInterval(my_game);
   speed = normal_speed;
   my_game = setInterval(game, speed);
   break;
 }
}

function endGame() {
  clearInterval(my_game);
 context.fillStyle = "yellow";
 context.font="20px Georgia";
 context.fillText("Game Over!", 10, 50);
  x_direction = 0;
  y_direction = 0;
  trail = [];
  tail = 5;
  normal_speed = 1000 / 10
  speed = 1000 / 10;
  game_status = 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  margin-top: 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 40px;
  background: salmon;
  border: none;
}

button:hover {
  background: lightsalmon;
}

canvas {
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="web_style.css">
  <canvas id = "gc" width = "400" height = "400"></canvas>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="snake_script.js"></script>
</head>



<body>

  <h1>Snake</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Timing functions don't guarantee that their callback will be called at that exact time you specify. They guarantee that's the minimum time until they fire. Long-running code will freeze the thread - JS is single threaded, thus the timers are prevented from running. I'm not saying that's what's happening with your code but this answers your title question.

Comment: so what do you suggest to solve this problem?

Comment: I've run the code and cannot reproduce the issue.